# cannot convert MethodHandle(Dates)JodaCompatibleZonedDateTime to (Object)double

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-scripting

I am trying to add conditions if field exist, then sort according to it otherwise use another field. Since one of either will exist.
Here is my query:

```
GET /my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "type":"number",
      "script": "if(doc['contextDates.event.date'].value != 0){ return doc['contextDates.event.date'].value} else { return doc['contextDates.start.date'].value}",
    "order": "asc"
    }
  }
}
```

When I execute this query, I get following error:

```
"failed_shards" : [
      {
        "shard" : 0,
        "index" : "my_inedx",
        "node" : "UxKwS8SIR-uIbzo5_0IbcQ",
        "reason" : {
          "type" : "script_exception",
          "reason" : "runtime error",
          "script_stack" : [
            "return doc['contextDates.event.date'].value} else { ",
            "                                     ^---- HERE"
          ],
          "script" : "if(doc['contextDates.event.date'].value != 0){ return doc['contextDates.event.date'].value} else { return doc['contextDates.start.date'].value}",
          "lang" : "painless",
          "position" : {
            "offset" : 84,
            "start" : 47,
            "end" : 99
          },
          "caused_by" : {
            "type" : "wrong_method_type_exception",
            "reason" : "cannot convert MethodHandle(Dates)JodaCompatibleZonedDateTime to (Object)double"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

I have tried `Double.parseDouble` method as well but it doesn't work. This is what I have inside document for `contextDates`

```
"contextDates" : {
        "event" : {
         "date" : "2020-06-26T00:00:00.000Z",
         "resolution" : "day",
         "score" : 0,
         "type" : "event"
       }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

The doc value you're getting is of type [`JodaCompatibleZonedDateTime`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/7.16/painless-api-reference-shared-org-elasticsearch-script.html#painless-api-reference-shared-JodaCompatibleZonedDateTime) which you're trying to compare to a double value, so you need to modify your script like this

```
if(doc['contextDates.event.date'].value.getMillis() != 0){ return doc['contextDates.event.date'].value.getMillis()} else { return doc['contextDates.start.date'].value.getMillis()}
```